# MySQL Workbench reports ERROR 1822: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm creating a mysql db based from an EER model sql script and when trying to do the conversion (all in MySQL Workbench), I'm getting the error above. My goal is to reference the adoption_entity_id on the adoption_entity table from 2 columns in attachment table (sent_from and from_to).

I have 2 tables, one of which is the attachment:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `afth_db`.`attachment`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `afth_db`.`attachment` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `afth_db`.`attachment` (
  `attachment_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `sent_from` INT NULL,
  `sent_to` INT NULL,
  `attachment_description` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `attachment_uploaded` DATETIME NULL,
  `attachment_uploaded_by` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `adoption_case_num` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`attachment_id`),
  INDEX `fk_attachment_adoption_case1_idx` (`adoption_case_num` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `attachment_id_UNIQUE` (`attachment_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `adoption_case_num_UNIQUE` (`adoption_case_num` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_attachment_adoption_entity1_idx` (`sent_from` ASC, `sent_to` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `sent_to_UNIQUE` (`sent_to` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `sent_from_UNIQUE` (`sent_from` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_attachment_adoption_case1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`adoption_case_num`)
    REFERENCES `afth_db`.`adoption_case` (`case_num`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_attachment_adoption_entity1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sent_from` , `sent_to`)
    REFERENCES `afth_db`.`adoption_entity` (`adoption_entity_id` , `adoption_entity_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

and the other is the adoption entity:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `afth_db`.`adoption_entity`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `afth_db`.`adoption_entity` (
  `adoption_entity_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `adoption_entity_type` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`adoption_entity_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `adoption_entity_id_UNIQUE` (`adoption_entity_id` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

The error states in detail:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1822: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'fk_attachment_adoption_entity1' in the referenced table 'adoption_entity'
```

I'm not sure why its been giving me this issue though. I've tried several solutions from setting type to 'unique index', 'index' for fk_attachment_adoption_entity1 along with the other columns involved, but I can't seem to be able to get rid of the error. I've also tried deleting and recreating the 1-1 relationship but that didnt help either. Can anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong here on the EER model design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create **one** foreign key reference, which spans over the two columns `sent_from` and `sent_to` to single rows in the `adoption_entity` table. That's not what you want. You want to create **two** separate foreign key references instead for the individual columns `sent_from` and `sent_to`. So the constraint parts should look like this:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_attachment_adoption_entity_from`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sent_from`)
    REFERENCES `afth_db`.`adoption_entity` (`adoption_entity_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION),
CONSTRAINT `fk_attachment_adoption_entity_to`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sent_to`)
    REFERENCES `afth_db`.`adoption_entity` (`adoption_entity_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```